# ¿Cómo poner titulo centrado en un string?

Tags: html, css, string

Tengo la siguiente cadena de texto en un `string`, pero quisiera que la frase "primeros pasos" aparezca en negrita, centrada y de otro color como un título,  que debería hacer?

```
<string name="primeros_pasos">PRIMEROS PASOS El primer día de Nisán del 5532 (4 de abril de 1772), en una pequeña....</string>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deberías poner las palabras que quieres destacar dentro de una etiqueta (por ejemplo un span, pero podrías utilizar otras), y luego con css darle el estilo que desees:

```css
    #palabras-destacadas {
        display:block;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:red;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
    <string name="primeros_pasos"><span id="palabras-destacadas">PRIMEROS PASOS</span> El primer día de Nisán del 5532 (4 de abril de 1772), en una pequeña....</string>
```

Pulsa en "ejecutar" para ver el ejemplo.

**UPDATE:**

El CSS puedes ponerlo directamente en la misma página en la que estás trabajando, o bien definirlos en un archivo aparte (externo). A no ser que sea algo especial o puntual, mi recomendación es que los pongas siempre en un archivo externo, pues no sólo es una manera más correcta sino que además verás que todo queda mucho más limpio y ordenado.

Si los quisieses poner directamente en tu página, lo harías dentro de la etiqueta *head*, así:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #palabras-destacadas {
        display:block;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:red;
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

Si deseas ponerlos en un archivo externo, deberías poner la etiqueta *style* con la referencia a la ruta a dicho archivo también en el *head*, de esta forma:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ruta_tu_archivo/estilos.css">
</head>
```

Donde tu archivo *estilos.css* tendría directamente el css con todos los estilos que desees poner en tu página.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: gracias amigo! no sabes cuanto me ayudaste!

Comment: Hola amigo. Lo que hiciste es exactamente lo que quiero hacer. Pero no se donde poner el codigo css que pones con #palabras destacadas. Podrias ayudarme?

Comment: @AsherCacua, he actualizado la respuesta para que veas donde se ponen. Espero habertelo aclarado. Un saludo!

Answer (score 6):

Aplica esto

```css
.title{
 color:blue;
 text-transform:uppercase; /*lo transformo a mayuscula*/
 display:block; /*lo vuelvo elemento bloque para que todo lo demas se vaya para abajo*/
 font-weight:600; /*lo hago negrita en un 600*/
 font-size:2.5rem; /*determina el tamaño de mi titulo , esta es una medida relativa depende del vanegador*/
 text-align:center; /*center- centro ; left-izquierda ; right- derecha */
 padding-bottom:15px;/*le digo que me de espacio para abajo de 15px*/
}
```

```html
<string name="primeros_pasos">
   <span class="title">primeros pasos</span>
   El primer día de Nisán del 5532 (4 de abril de 1772), en una pequeña....
</string>
```

Comment: hola muchas gracias, soy nuevo en esto, no se donde colocar el codigo que pones antes: .title{
 color:blue;
 text-transform:uppercase; /*lo transformo a mayuscula*/
 display:block; /*lo vuelvo elemento bloque para que todo lo demas se vaya para abajo*/
 font-weight:600; /*lo hago negrita en un 600*/
}

Comment: lo pones asi 
   </body> 
   <style>.title{
 color:blue;
 text-transform:uppercase; /*lo transformo a mayuscula*/
 display:block; /*lo vuelvo elemento bloque para que todo lo demas se vaya para abajo*/
 font-weight:600; /*lo hago negrita en un 600*/
}
</style> y YA QUEDO

Comment: agrega una explicacion de tu clase `.title` en la respuesta no en el comentario css

Answer (score 4):

Hola para implementar lo que te sugirió Cooper debes primero crear tu código CSS, para ello crea una carpeta con el nombre CSS en la raíz de tu proyecto, dentro de esta crea un archivo el cual guardaras con la extensión **.css** al final del nombre (**Ejemplo: main.css**) en este archivo vas a copiar el código CSS aportado por Cooper, luego en la pagina donde quieres que se muestre el estilo vas a realizar el llamado del archivo css con la siguiente etiqueta

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"
```

esta colócala antes de la etiqueta `head` de tu pagina y obviamente debes colocar el texto tal cual lo indica Cooper en la pagina

```
(string name="primeros_pasos"span id="palabras-destacadas"PRIMEROS PASOS El primer día de Nisán del 5532 (4 de abril de 1772), en una pequeña..../string).
```

Cualquier duda comenta para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score -2):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```html
<string name="primeros_pasos" align="center"> PRIMEROS PASOS El primer día de Nisán del 5532 (4 de abril de 1772), en una pequeña....</string>
```

o bien

```html
<string name="primeros_pasos">
        <div align="center"> PRIMEROS PASOS El primer día de Nisán del 5532 (4 de abril de 1772), en una pequeña....
        </div>
    </string>
```